# Debugging in Unity3d with emacs?

Tags: debugging, gud

I develop in Unity, and have been using emacs as my text editor for development. Debugging however has always needed to be done through monodevelop (and it crashes half the time while doing this). My team finally updated our unity version and that came with an updated mono version that I was hoping could maybe allow me to hook the GUD up to the Unity Debugger? The only help I could find was [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024891/using-the-mono-soft-debugger-with-emacs) pointing at the mono soft debugger, but its from a number of years ago and I dont know how I would hook into the running unity instance. Has anyone solved this problem before?